# Display of form inputs broken by my custom angular material theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to setup a custom angular material theme for my app. I have setup my custom theme as follows:

from `styles.scss`:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
@import "portal-theme";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

from `portal-theme.scss`:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@import "portal-palettes";

$portal-primary: mat.define-palette($portal-primary-palette);
$portal-accent: mat.define-palette($portal-secondary-palette);
$portal-warn: mat.define-palette($portal-warn-palette);

$portal-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $portal-primary,
    accent: $portal-accent,
    warn: $portal-warn
  )
));

@include mat.core-theme($portal-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($portal-theme);
```

from `portal-palettes.scss`:

```
$portal-primary-palette: (
  50 : #e0eaf1,
  100 : #b3cbdb,
  200 : #80a8c4,
  300 : #4d85ac,
  400 : #266b9a,
  500 : #005188,
  600 : #004a80,
  ...
```

However, if I remove this line from `styles.scss`:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

then **the display of all my forms inputs breaks**... I thought I would not need this prebuilt theme since I have created my own.

Can someone please help me understand why I need this line and what is missing in my custom theme? Why does the display of my forms and form inputs break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following line to the bottom of my `portal-theme.scss` file:

```
@include mat.core();
```

This seems to fix the broken form display.

The `portal-theme.scss` is now as follows:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@import "portal-palettes";

$portal-primary: mat.define-palette($portal-primary-palette);
$portal-accent: mat.define-palette($portal-secondary-palette);
$portal-warn: mat.define-palette($portal-warn-palette);

$portal-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $portal-primary,
    accent: $portal-accent,
    warn: $portal-warn
  )
));

@include mat.core(); // Addition that fixes the broken display issue
@include mat.core-theme($portal-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($portal-theme);
```